# How to access python enums in protobufs

Tags: python, enums, protocol-buffers

In my protobuf file called **skill.proto**, I have:

```
message Cooking {
    enum VegeType {
        CAULIFLOWER = 0;
        CUCUMBER = 1;
    }
    required VegeType type = 1;
}
```

In another file (eg: name.py) I want to set the cooking type to cucumber. ie:

```
co = skill_pb2.Cooking()
co.type = skill_pb2.cooking.type.CUCUMBER
```

so that last line there doesn't work. **How do I set co.type to CUCUMBER?**

NB: I want to avoid doing co.type = 1

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just a typo and some capitalization.

```
skill_pb2.Cooking.CUCUMBER
```

See https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial

---

Update: There are now three possible methods for [accessing enums](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#enum) in protobuf:

```
skill_pb2.Cooking.CUCUMBER
skill_pb2.Cooking.VegeType.CUCUMBER
skill_pb2.Cooking.VegeTypeValue.Value('CUCUMBER')
```

with the second one being more recent as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/6028).

Comment: I think the method has been changed, I had to do this to get it to work:
`skill_pb2.Cooking.VegeType.Value('CUCUMBER')`

Comment: The docs for enums are comical at best: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial#enums